# Am I allowed to use meta.stackexchange to complain about my questions being closed?

Tags: discussion

Am I allowed to use meta.stackexchange to complain about my questions being closed?

I've tried, and the questions on meta just get closed and downvoted. Is that misuse of meta.stackexchange and this subsite is not really meant for raising concerns, only for changes to the site rules?

Comment: I see no problem with asking why a specific question was closed.

Comment: It is usually more productive to post an argument as to why the question should not have been closed instead of complaining. It might attract attention of users who would not otherwise pay attention, and perhaps even change minds. The site's policies are largely established by the community, reasoning about them is exactly what Meta is for.

Comment: +1 @Conifold thanks

Answer (score 8):

If you use meta just to *complain* about your questions being closed, it's unlikely to accomplish much - and, as you've apparently experienced, such metas are likely to be downvoted and/or closed for not being a productive use of anyone's time.

However, you can certainly use it to ask others why your post was closed, and ask for improvements. People might be able to provide more in-depth feedback and either help you rephrase your question in an acceptable fashion or direct you to somewhere that the original question would be more appropriate.

(That said: admittedly, I don't spend much time on Philosophy.SE, but this is how most site metas are used - to either clarify/establish policy or ask about specific questions and how they can be improved/why certain action was taken.)